# Reflection - GetProperties of a class that are Interfaces

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using refelection to iterate through the Public properties of a class.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in instance.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  ...do work
```

This gets me all public properties. However I only want to get Public Properties that are interfaces. For example below i want to get 'session' (which is an Interface) but not Help.

```
public ISession Session { get; set; } //My Interface - i want this

public string Help { get; set; } //I dont want this
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Type.IsInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinterface%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine if the type of a property is an interface type.

```
Type t = typeof ( YourType );

foreach ( PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties () )
{
    if ( p.PropertyType.IsInterface )
    {
        // p is an interface property
    }
}
```